# SystemVerilog - With an enum can you have a range?

Tags: enums, verilog, system-verilog

With a typedef enum can you have a range for un-assigned values? For example:

```
typedef bit [3:0] enum {BLUE = 4'h0, RED = 4'h1, OTHERS = 4'h2 to 4'hF};
```

Or something similar? What will happen if a user chooses a value that is unassigned also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enums in System-Verilog can have out of range values. This is particularly useful when describing FSMs using enums if you choose a *four-state* type as the *base type*, eg:

```
//           a four-state base type (with default value 3'bxxx)
//               |
//               |      the base value of IDLE will be 3'b000
//               |        |
//               V        V
typedef enum logic[2:0] {IDLE, GO1, GO2} state_type;
state_type state;
```

The default type of `logic` is `x`, so by default the variable `state` above will have the value `3'bxxx`. Therefore, by using a four-state base type, we can model an uninitialised state, which checks that the FSM has been reset properly.

So, you ask "What will happen if an user choose a value that is unassigned also?" The variable will have that value and, as in Serge's `case` example, in will not be equal to any of the defined enumeration values.

Comment: I'm trying to understand how to model the uninitialised state to ensure that the FSM is reset properly, but I'm stuck. Could you give me an snippet example?

Comment: @bu-ral If you use the above in standard FSM code, the FSM will not work until the FSM is reset, because the value of the variable `state` will not be `IDLE`. You just need the code above and standard FSM code.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have ranges in the enum. However the rest depends on how you would use it. For example, in the case statement:

```
case(sel)
  BLUE: do-blue-function;
  RED: do-red-function;
  default: do-other-function;
endcase
```